# How to setup Travis CI for an Android Project which uses both NDK and SDK to build

Tags: android, android-ndk, travis-ci

I've searched in so many places, even in Travis CI documentation page but I couldn't find the solution of my problem. The issue is - **I already have an Android Project set up on Travis CI which works fine. Now, I have some requirement where I need to compile some native files for my project**. In my local machine, the set up works perfectly as I've `SDK` and `NDK` installed. When I push the code the Travis complains about the `NDK`. So, I looked for how to set up the **NDK** for Travis. I followed below links ---

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/.travis.yml

[Travis: how to know android sdk/ndk path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090358/travis-how-to-know-android-sdk-ndk-path?rq=1)

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5395

But none of the above worked. My `travis.yml` file is in below --

```
# which language/platform is used
language: android
# JDK version
jdk:
- oraclejdk8

# root permission required?
sudo: required
dist: precise

# Environment variables
env:
  global:
  - BRANCH_NAME=$TRAVIS_BRANCH

# android components required to build code
android:
  components:
  - tools
  - platform-tools
  - build-tools-25.0.3
  - android-24
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - extra-google-m2repository
  - extra-google-google_play_services

# clean up old stuff before we get started
before_cache:
- rm -f $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock

# cache directories to use
cache:
  directories:
  - "$HOME/.gradle/caches/"
  - "$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/"

# Configurations to set up Android NDK
before_install:
    - rm -fr $HOME/android-ndk-r16b
    - curl -L http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip -O
    - unzip -oq android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip
    - rm android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip
    - export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$HOME/android-ndk-r16b
    - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}

# Build script - which configs and creates the builds
script: "./my_script.sh"
```

With this setup Travis CI recognizes the **NDK** but while running my build script it's unable to find it. Below is the log for my Travis build --

```
android.install
Installing Android dependencies
creating directory /home/travis/.gradle/caches
adding /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper to cache
creating directory /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper
$ java -Xmx32m -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
$ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
javac 1.8.0_111
before_install.1
$ rm -fr $HOME/android-ndk-r16b
before_install.2
$ curl -L http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip -O
before_install.3
$ unzip -oq android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip
before_install.4
$ rm android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip
before_install.5
$ export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$HOME/android-ndk-r16b
before_install.6
$ export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}
$ ./build_cc_app.sh
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /home/travis/android-ndk-r16b.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':client'.
> NDK not configured. /home/travis/android-ndk-r16b
  Download it with SDK manager.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 29.479 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of hassle and lots of debugging sessions on Travis CI builds, I figured out the way to solve this issue. Apparently, the default `android` tool-chain searches for `NDK` in its `SDK` directory. As it was not able to find that, it was complaining for the `NDK`. So, I had to use the Default tool chain to get the `NDK`. Below is a snapshot of my `.travis.yml` file which points to the changes that I made to resolve this issue.

[image]

To find the answer why I added `tools` twice, you can refer to this [link](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/). Refer to below image to figure out which portion of the Doc to refer for the answer.

[image]

So, as it's mentioned in the Travis CI documentation, when we want to build an Android Project with `SDK` level **24**, we need to use the `tools` options twice in the `yml` script.

And then as I was using `ndk-build` to build my native files, I just had to add below part in the `yml` script.

```
# Configurations to set up Android NDK
before_install:
  - echo y | sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
```

One thing to remember. I was using `C` language for native project. If you are using `C++`, then you might need to install `Cmake` for that. Below is the code for that --

```
 before_install:
   - echo y | sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
   - echo y | sdkmanager "cmake;3.6.4111459" # (Check the Cmake version you want to use)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it is missing the `platforms` directory. You could probably investigate further by requesting that debug is enabled on your repository:

[Running build in debug](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/)

> This feature is available for private repositories and those public
>   repositories for which the feature is enabled. To have the feature
>   enabled for a public repository, please email us at
>   support@travis-ci.com indicating which ones. Push access to the
>   repository is also required.

I have found Travis are quite quick to respond but you'll also need to set up your commandline client:

[Travis commandline client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#readme)

Comment: I ran the same build in debug mode. When I attached to the debugging session, I can see `plaforms` directory under `android-ndk-r16b` folder. And as I set my NDK Home to that folder, Travis should be able to find that. But still it's not able to find that.

Comment: Have you tried executing the build with `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`?

Comment: I tried that too. But it didn't help. It didn't give no other information except the same which I've given in Travis log. :(

Comment: what is the gradle version being used on Travis?

Comment: I'm using `gradle` wrapper and the wrapper version is 3.3